# How to concatenate and format specific parts of the output

Tags: excel, vba, format, concatenation

Suppose we have a table with hundreds of rows and dozens of columns such as this one:

[image]

What I need to accomplish is to concatenate the content of the columns B, F, M in a new sheet with the following format:

[image]

Let's explain better, I have to put the content of column B in parenthesis and bold font and concatenate on the same line the content of the column F and also concatenate with a line feed the content of column M in italic font.

While I can perform this through excel formulas and change the format of the output manually, I am required to do this for all the rows of the table, so VBA is the only feasible to solve this.

Please, I ask for the assistance of any VBA experts out there.

This is the formula used for the desired output for only a specific row of the table: `="("&Sheet1!B2&")"&Sheet1!F2&CHAR(10)&Sheet1!M2`

What I am looking for is a sort of VBA code that is able concatenate the content in the specified format (bold, line feed, italic) of the 3 different columns for all the rows of the table in a new sheet.

As requested, this is the VBA code recorded after manually formatting the output after the concatenate operation for the first arrow of the 3 columns:

```
   Range("B2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "(SPC-PRO-001)TEXT1: random" & Chr(10) & "Full"
    With ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=0).Font
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .FontStyle = "Regular"
        .Size = 11
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
    End With
    With ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=13).Font
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .FontStyle = "Bold"
        .Size = 11
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
    End With
    With ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=14, Length:=14).Font
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .FontStyle = "Regular"
        .Size = 11
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
    End With
    With ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=28, Length:=4).Font
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .FontStyle = "Italic"
        .Size = 11
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
    End With
```

I am fully aware that most of this code is redundant and only valid for the first arrow of the table. What I am asking for assistance is for a code valid for all the arrows of the table, which entails measuring lengths for each cell of the same arrow to specify desired formatting (bold or italic) and for loop to cover all the arrows of the table.

Comment: When you tried writing the code yourself, what specific problem did you run into?

Comment: I have not written any VBA code yet. That's why I opened this question, I know that in order to format the specific text output of a concatenate operation in Excel is required to write some VBA lines.

The only thing I can provide in terms of code is the formula used to get the output (without formatting) I am looking forward to accomplish, although only for one row of the whole table: ="("&Sheet1!B2&")"&Sheet1!F2&CHAR(10)&Sheet1!M2

Comment: I understand your problem and have some proposal of solution. I do not understand why this topic has been closed. Problem is a bit complex, because the result of a formula (in the cell that contains formula) cannot be formatted individually (on a character basis), so if you want a formula it must produce the result in another cell, and this is a non-trivial task. Another way is a macro that converts initial non-formatted results into formatted text constants. But this way you lose origin of your formulas.

Comment: I have proceeded to record a Macro to see the VBA code generated while formatting the output after the concatenation. The main issue doing this is that the start and length of the text to be formatted ( ".Characters(Start:=1, Length:=13).Font.FontStyle = Bold/Italic") depends on the size of each row of the column F which would be variable.

So, I would need to check the length of each cell to be concatenated and apply the formatting according to this.

For the record, I am only interested in getting the formatted output, the formula was a way to get the desired output without any format.

Comment: It is as you wrote. To format text at the character level, you need to read the length of each part of the text before merging, or alternatively, after joining, look for the position of characteristic characters (closing parenthesis, newline break). To format some of the text, you need to provide a starting character position and the number of characters to format.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the result is needed on Sheet2, the code create in column A the unformatted text, and in column B the formatted one.

```
Sub boldital()
    Dim trange As Range, target As Worksheet, sourcesheet As Worksheet
    
    Set target = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set sourcesheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lastrow = sourcesheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To lastrow
        a = sourcesheet.Range("B" & i)
        b = sourcesheet.Range("F" & i)
        c = sourcesheet.Range("M" & i)
        alen = Len(a)
        blen = Len(b)
        clen = Len(c)
        sumtext = "(" & a & ")" & b & Chr(10) & c
        Set trange = target.Range("B" & i)
        trange.Offset(0, -1) = sumtext
        trange = sumtext
        If alen <> 0 Then trange.Characters(2, alen).Font.Bold = TRUE
        If clen <> 0 Then trange.Characters(4 + alen + blen, clen).Font.Italic = TRUE
    Next i
End Sub
```